# how to find the cause of ActiveRecord ROLLBACK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the logs I'm seeing a `ROLLBACK`, but no exception is logged. Is there a way to find out what caused the ROLLBACK?

Here's the excerpt of the log:

```
  Phone Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "phones".* FROM "phones" WHERE "phones"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 980190963]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."phone_id" = 980190963 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Phone Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "phones".* FROM "phones" WHERE "phones"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 980190963]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."phone_id" = 980190963 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What is in the log around that ROLLBACK?

Comment: No errors. Also, it's weird that one time it uses a transaction, the next time it doesn't. Unless those two pieces are unrelated.

Comment: Any idea what causes that SELECT inside the transaction?

Comment: May be you are doing some save/update. Can you paste the code corresponding to the log?

Comment: I cleaned up my code and this problem doesn't show up anymore. I don't know what it was.

Comment: I have the same problem. There are no errors or exceptions. I've even tried catching an exception; nothing. As for details, this is happening inside a callback on a relationship with a through association.

Comment: Figured out my problem: rails doesn't like it when you modify an associated model that has a through association, during a callback whether its in the model or observer. There were no exceptions messages or anything; just rollbacks.

Answer (score 113):

save record with BANG '!' so it will make a run time error and you get know where does it happens

Comment: I don't know. In my case I'm getting a ROLLBACK on a `destroy` in which case the selected answer seems to help me but this one doesn't apply.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times. It's saved me multiple times.

Comment: Thanks mate, i found the problem very quickly! (<- did u get it? haha)

Answer (score 52):

One way is to manually write information to the log. Try something like this from your controller:

```
Rails.logger.info(@your_object.errors.inspect)
```

That should output the content of all validations that failed.

Answer (score 24):

1) Disable **before_create, before_save, before_update** and check where it saves the day

2) If rollback was caused by one of those methods, check that those methods return true when you don't plan to rollback.

For example if you set default value for boolean field to avoid nil, you would probably do it this way

```
def set_defaults_before_create
  self.my_boolean_field ||= false
end
```

In this example method **set_defaults_before_create** always returns **false** and thus rollbacks your transaction. So refactor it to return true

```
def set_defaults_before_create
  self.my_boolean_field ||= false
  true
end
```

Comment: I spent about a day trying to debug this issue. Thanks a lot : )

Comment: Second point solve mine. Methods needs to return true, I think it is used for validation purpose even when we are using it for other purpose.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I defined a function `destroy` inside a model, to delete additional files related to the record from disk, then if the files where missing, the function returned not true, so I added the `true` in the last line and everything fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The 3 methodologies (1 failed) I have come up with are to

1. use an observer on active record on all the relevant save, validate methods
2. to open up active record and put a debugger statement where ROLLBACKs are triggered and then run `caller` to pinpoint the code that triggered the error.
3. Failed :override the active record methods and pause on exception. If I remember this method does not catch any exception because the save methods are wrapped in a transaction.

Notes: Only enable when the mode is not Rails.env.production?. Tested on Rails 3.2.13, using ruby 1.9.3.

1. Observer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers

   class ActiveRecordObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

   ```
   observe "ActiveRecord::Base"

   def after_validation(model)
       debugger if model.errors.messages.any?
       Rails.logger.error "after validation"
   end
   def before_update(model)
       debugger if !model.valid?
       Rails.logger.error "before update"
   end
   def after_update(model)
       debugger if !model.valid?
       Rails.logger.error "after update"
   end
   def before_save(model)

       debugger if model.errors.messages.any?
       Rails.logger.error "#{model}"
       Rails.logger.error "before save"
   end
   def after_save(model)
       debugger if model.errors.messages.any?
       Rails.logger.error "after save"
   end
   ```

   end

NOTE: To use Observers in recent Rails versions (from v.4 up to the most recent v.6), you need to bundle `gem 'rails-observers'` in Gemfile (best if enclosed inside a :development and :test group), put the class under `app/observers/active_record_observer.rb`, and register the observer in your current environment config file (e.g. `config/environments/development.rb`) by placing (or adding to) this line: `config.active_record.observers = [:active_record_observer]`

2)
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L231
cd `bundle show activerecord`

```
     Put a debugger statement when where the rollback is executed.
    /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-<env>/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb

   196              transaction_open = false
   197              decrement_open_transactions
   198              if open_transactions == 0
   199                rollback_db_transaction
   200                debugger
=> 201                rollback_transaction_records(true)
   202              else
   203                rollback_to_savepoint
   204                debugger
   205                rollback_transaction_records(false)
```

When the rails server or console hits the breakpoint type in `caller` to get the backtrace.

3. Override AR in development mode. TODO: only override  if !Rails.env.production?
   Put this in `app/config/initializers/active_record_or_any_file_name.rb`

   ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
   alias_method :old_save, :save
   alias_method :old_save!, :save!
   def save(*args)
   begin
   puts "#{self} save"
   Rails.logger.info "#{self} save"
   old_save(*args)
   rescue Exception => e
   debugger
   puts e
   end
   end
   def save!(*args)
   begin
   Rails.logger.info "#{self} save!"
   puts "#{self} save!"
   old_save!(*args)
   rescue Exception => e
   debugger
   puts e
   end
   end
   end

Comment: I had a similar issue where rollback was not due to any exception and hence no rescue block would give a reason. Following @davidtimgsu's suggestion to put a debug point helped in localising it. In ActiveRecord 5.2.3, under `active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb` there is a line that reads `Thread.current.status == "aborting"`. This was the cause for rollbacks in mine because an external process was terminating the current thread and all transactions in ensure statements in current thread were being rolled back.

Comment: To use Observers in Rails over  version 4 (up to the most recent v.6), you need to bundle `gem 'rails-observers'` in Gemfile, put the class under `app/observers/active_record_observer.rb`, and register the observer in your current environment config file (e.g. `config/environments/development.rb` by placing (or adding to) this line: `config.active_record.observers = [:active_record_observer]`

Answer (score 0):

In my case a `has_many` association was defined with `dependent: :restrict_with_error` instead of `dependent: :destroy`. It was defined in a concern so I didn't see it immediately. Anyway, it would be nice if Rails told us what causes a Rollback to happen :-)